# How can I send request from Shopify to an external API?

Tags: request, shopify, backend, integration

I'm trying to make an integration between Shopify and an external bank API.

The integration is simple, is just request a JWT in the bank endpoint, sending data, and receive a response. My problem is that I have never used Shopify, and I'm not sure if it has a backend to make all this process and how does it works or where could I find it. I search in Google but I didn't found a clear answer for this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You most probably need to create a custom shopify app: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/custom-apps

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple ways to do this, all depends what you need.

1. search on settings / payment methods if this bank has already a connection with shopify
2. Search on [shopify apps store](https://apps.shopify.com) if already exist a shopify app for this bank.
3. If don't exists you can do your own app. there you have two options [public or custom apps](https://shopify.dev/apps/distribution)

If I was you I'll do a public app because I can sell to more shopify customers interested on use the same bank, you can even sell the app to the bank itself on the future.

You should follow the directives from [shopify dev](https://shopify.dev/apps)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250522/cors-error-when-using-shopify-admin-api-in-front-end